# play framework 2.2.2 routing multiple different query params, Ember - data redirect status

Tags: ember.js, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play 2.2.2. I have apis of the form

```
/users?token=abcd
/users?resetToken=abcd
```

I have configured my route as follows:

```
GET /users      controllers.X.method(token: String)
GET /users      controllers.Y.method(resetToken: String)
```

Now, when I make a call to the /users?resetToken=tokenvalue, I get the following error

```
For request 'GET /users?resetToken=tokenvalue' [Missing parameter: token]
```

I could have solved this by routing both the apis to the same method and then checking the query params inside the method. But I want to route the apis to two different methods because of the access restrictions on each of them. One of the apis can be accessed only after login while the other can be accessed with/without login.

Could you please help me resolve the issue?

(Adding more information:)
I tried the following:

```
GET  /users                      controllers.A.genericMethod()
GET  /usersByToken/:token        controllers.X.method(token: String)
GET  /usersByResetToken/:token   controllers.Y.method(token: String)
```

In controllers.A,

```
public static Promise<Result> genericMethod(){
    Map<String, String[]> queryParams = Context.current().request().queryString();
    String[] tokens = queryParams.get("token");
    String[] resetTokens = queryParams.get("resetToken");
    if (tokens != null && tokens.length == 1) {
        return Promise.pure((Result) redirect(controllers.routes.X.method(tokens[0])));
    } else if (resetTokens != null && resetTokens.length == 1) {
        return Promise.pure((Result) redirect(controllers.routes.Y.method(resetTokens[0])));
    } else {
        ObjectNode node = ControllerHelper.error(ResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Required params not set!");
        return Promise.pure((Result) badRequest(node));
    }
}
```

In controllers.X

```
@SubjectPresent
public static Promise<Result> method(){
....
}
```

In controllers.Y

```
public static Promise<Result> method(){
....
}
```

This works from the play framework point of view. 
But I am calling these apis from ember framework through ember-data. So, if I make a call to it from ember-data, say using

```
this.store.find('user', {token: "abcd"});
```

which forms the corresponding api url

```
/users?token=abcd
```

I get a response of "303, see other" and the required data is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare two routes with the same method and path, fortunately you don't have to, you have two solutions, first is declaring '***Optional parameters***' (@see: [doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaRouting)) like

```
GET  /users    controllers.X.action(token ?= null, resetToken ?= null)

public static Result action(String token, String resetToken){
    if (token==null) debug("No token given...");
    // etc
}
```

Other solution is declaring rout w/out params, as you can still get arguments with [DynamicForm](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html)

```
GET  /users    controllers.X.action()

public static Result action(){
    DynamicForm dynamicForm = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    String token = dynamicForm.get("token");
    if (token==null) debug("No token given...");
    // etc
}
```

Second approach is better especially if your API has large amount of optional params.

Note: *Written from top of my head*

Comment: Hi, in my latest edits to the question, I have used the second approach. I am using redirects to the corresponding actions in the genericMethod in order to enforce the access restrictions applied on the corresponding actions controllers.X.method and controllers.Y.method. I want to know if it is possible to call the corresponding actions along with their access restrictions without using redirect.

Comment: don't use redirect to the other action but return... other action like: `return otherAction(arg1, arg2);` anyway TBH I have no idea how it will work with `Promise<Result>`

Comment: In short, is it possible to call an action from another action along with its access restrictions?

Comment: I tried `return otherAction(arg1)`. But the problem is the access restrictions which I have added as annotations to the action does not apply when I call this way.

Comment: IMHO: Add restrictions to the main method and make sure there is no route added to the otherAction, so your main action will check it, the worst problem will be if you'll need to use different access...

Comment: Yes, I need two different access restrictions. One of them has to work only when the user is logged in, the other should work whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: So don't use restriction annotations, but check if user is logged inside the action... sorry for laconic answer, but I'd need to check the whole scenario, before giving better options

Comment: That's my last resort. I am hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: For now, I am going with checking if the user is logged inside the action. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that one api is protected, requiring a login, and another does not.

You need to have two separate routes, this is the best way.

```
GET /users             controllers.X.method(token: String)
GET /public/users      controllers.Y.method(resetToken: String)
```

Combining it into one route will not allow you to have separate access restrictions.

You need to break it into two routes, one with a private access and one with a public access.

This will change your apis obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot change the apis. The urls are generated by ember-data.